# Is there an equivalent to cv2.minMaxLoc in pyautogui?

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui

OpenCV has a function **cv2.minMaxLoc()**. This function allows you to return the **max_val** which is the pixel with the best match to whatever image you're searching for.

You can **print(max_val)** to see how close a match your image actually is, even if doesn't find a match, it'll still return the closest possible match as a decimal.

pyautogui has [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) that shows that you can use the **confidence** parameter if OpenCV is installed which seems similar to how threshold matching works with OpenCV.

Is there an equivalent for pyautogui? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: I don't think pyautogui offers this yet. You want a function that does a match and gives you the score, right? My guess for pyautogui is that they are using on of the normalized template match modes and minMaxLoc. For `TM_CCORR_NORMED` and `TM_CCOEFF_NORMED` you get numbers between 0 and 1. Why not use the OpenCV functions?

Comment: I was trying to stick to pyautogui for this project, it's easy enough to do this in OpenCV. Just a lockdown project, everything else so far is working and writing in pyautogui. In reality, this is for a logging function I'm building. Any image found is being logged to a text file with it's location, I was wanting to add the confidence value it was found with to the log. I may try and just use the openCV value but then I think I need to use openCV for my matching then rather than pyautogui which means some re-writing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked in the source code, and there is no confidence parameter without OpenCV. `pyautogui` uses [`pyscreeze`](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze) for all of the locate functions. `pyscreeze` autodetects if OpenCV is installed. If installed, it calls `cv2.matchTemplate` using the `cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED` match mode. If not installed, they use their own function (`_locateAll_python`)that I don't fully understand but I think it looks for a perfect match (confidence 1.000000...)

If you don't mind having OpenCV dependency, but just don't want code that directly calls OpenCV, you can either

1. talk maintainer into modifying `_locateAll_opencv` in pyscreeze to return actual confidence

or

2. hack your own local copy of `pyscreeze` so that it returns actual confidence.

Comment: Think I'm just going to call OpenCV. If pyautogui is using matchTemplate if OpenCV is installed (it is) surely that means I can call cv2.minMaxLoc() without having to rewrite my code? Not at my desk right now to check!

Answer (score -1):

According to libhunt :

PyAutoGUI alternatives and similar packages

- Selenium. 9.8 9.9 L2 PyAutoGUI VS Selenium. A browser automation framework and ecosystem.
- locust. 9.5 9.4 L3 PyAutoGUI VS locust. Scalable user load testing tool written in Python.
- splinter. 7.1 8.1 L5 PyAutoGUI VS splinter. ...
- sixpack. 6.1 0.0 L4 PyAutoGUI VS sixpack

Here is the link : https://python.libhunt.com/pyautogui-alternatives

Comment: Apologies! I was looking for similar functionality within pyautogui rather than a different package alltogether!